# Калькулятор Android (Парсинг)

Tags: android, функции, java, калькулятор

Здравствуйте.

Может есть у кого готовый метод для парсинга строки калькулятора и вычисления выражения?
На вход функции подаётся строка с выражением, а на выходе результат
Нужно только основные 4 действия (+, -, *, /), без скобок и прочего.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Компилятор выражений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/50139/).

> выражение: «x + 10 == 5 * y / (1 + z*2)»;
>
> требуется уметь вычислять это выражение для любых значений x, y и z.
>
> И конечно при этом надо учитывать приоритеты операторов.
>
> Для решения нужно сделать компилятор, который по строке строит объект «Вычислимое Выражение». У этого объекта будет метод «вычислить для данных значений переменных».

Comment: Мне не нужно столько кода, я интересуюсь, есть ли простенькое что-то для 4ех действий :) Но всё равно - спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

[Парсер формул с помощью метода рекурсивного спуска](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122397/).

Вот, когда то писал статью на хабре.

> Хочу поделится с вами реализацией алгоритма «Метод рекурсивного спуска» на примере написания парсера формул с поддержкой переменных и функций на языке Java

Comment: Мне не нужно столько кода, я интересуюсь, есть ли простенькое что-то для 4ех действий :) Но всё равно - спасибо!

Comment: ))))) может еще людям и код за тебя порезать ? выкинь от туда все лишние, если уж совсем простой велосипед нужен то просто  if else  помогут - немного извратно, но вполне реально

Comment: Да не прошу я ничего, готовое же спрашиваю :)

Comment: @NeoTvidoz вам уже дали аж 2 раза - имейте совесть!

Comment: 1 способ: устрой проход по строке, занося числа в массив. число начинается с пробела, +, или -. если после числа встречается * или / заноси в массив результат, перед тем как занести проверь что после числа другое число или конец строки, если * или / повторить еще раз, сложи все элементы массива  
2 способ: перепиши строку в другую, но вместо *, / записывай результат и так до тех пор пока в строке не останется знаков * и /. Потом просто складывай все числа, a - b == a + (-b)  
все это дикие велосипеды которые будут уступать в точности и скорости нормальным алгоритмам - дерзай